# IE 11 caching javascript overrides

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, caching, browser-cache

I've come across some weird behavior in IE11 when it comes to overriding functions in javascript.

On a webpage i have the following code:

```
(function ()
{
    var tempSetItem = window.localStorage.setItem;
    window.localStorage.setItem = function (key, data)
    {
        var newdata = JSON.stringify(data);
        newdata = JSON.parse(newdata);
        newdata.CachedDate = new Date();
        tempSetItem.call(window.localStorage, key, JSON.stringify(newdata));
    };
})();
```

This should simply override the `localStorage.setItem()` function.

However, i ran into some trouble with the code and decided to comment it out.
When i refreshed the page (cleared cache ofcourse) the same problem was still there.
I soon realised that IE had somehow cached my override.
I searched through all my files to make sure i didn't override it anywhere else and i even tried to set it to null manually through the console (In other words, it should not be null after a refresh) and after a refresh, it was now null.

It seems to be cached per domain or per URL in some way and i don't know how to clear this cache or if it's even possible.

I even tried repairing IE but localStorage.setItem is still null on my webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why the overriding gets cached but i found a way to reset it.
Calling `localStorage.clear()` resets the entire localStorage-object, including the setItem-function.

To avoid the rest of the problem i simply made a normal wrapper-function instead of overriding the original and called that from all the places where i would otherwise call `localStorage.setItem()`.